# Matrix returning wrong values in Java

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, multiplication

Im trying to make a method in java that multiplies two matrices using integers as arguments to tell where in the matrices Im working, and recursively "slice up" the matrices to smaller parts and multiply them together from here using the so called Divide and Conquer (it is a school task to do so, allthough it sure is a hard way to multiply two matrices!). Unsurprisingly, after my code have finished running, the matrice does not show what I would expect. In my main method, I have 3 matrices of size n*n (n=2, 4, 8, 16...), so they are squares. Im multiplying matrice A and B into matrice D. My main method is inside matrix class. This is how my code looks now:

```
public class indexMult {
matrix mat = new matrix();


public void calc(int Ay, int Ax, int By, int Bx, int Dy, int Dx, int size){

    System.out.println(Ay +" "+ Ax +" "+ By +" "+ Bx +" "+ Dy +" "+ Dx +" "+ size);
    if(size==2){

        mat.D[Dy][Dx] = mat.A[Ay][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];
        mat.D[Dy+1][Dx] = mat.A[Ay+1][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay+1][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];
        mat.D[Dy][Dx+1] = mat.A[Ay][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx+1];
        mat.D[Dy+1][Dx+1] = mat.A[Ay+1][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx+1] + mat.A[Ay+1][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];


    }else{

        size = size/2;  
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++){

                calc(i, j, i, j, i, j, size);
                calc(i, size+j, i, size+j, i, size+j, size);
                calc(size+i, j, size+i, j, size+i, j, size);
                calc(size+i, size+j, size+i, size+j, size+i, size+j, size);

            }   
        }           
    }
}
```

}

This method changes matrice D directly. To make it easier, Im using 2 in every spot in matrice A and B. There is also an issue in the way I have formulated my code, as the results are not right - but I have not come to this issue yet. My issue at this point is that no matter what I set n to, D only fills 5x5. If I use n as 4 or 2, I get an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception (because Im obviously trying to fill a 4x4 matrice with 5x5 data). But thats not what I want my code to do! The idea behind my code is to divide the n in n*n (int size) by 2, and from here do a recursive call with each quarter of the matrice until the size is 2x2 and I can solve that part. Im probably lacking a piece to add together the quarter matrices, but Im not that far yet - Im having trouble filling the whole matrice as it stops after 5x5. Are anyone able to spot the error??

EDIT:

With help from answer bellow, and some fixies myself, this change seems to work - not only for my issue, but to actually calculate what I need! :))

```
calc(Ay, Ax, By, Bx, Dy, Dx, size);
        calc(Ay, Ax+size, By+size, Bx, Dy, Dx, size);

        calc(Ay, Ax, By, Bx+size, Dy, Dx+size, size);
        calc(Ay, Ax+size, By+size, Bx+size, Dy, Dx+size, size);

        calc(Ay+size, Ax, By, Bx, Dy+size, Dx, size);
        calc(Ay+size, Ax+size, By+size, Bx, Dy+size, Dx, size);

        calc(Ay+size, Ax, By, Bx+size, Dy+size, Dx+size, size);
        calc(Ay+size, Ax+size, By+size, Bx+size, Dy+size, Dx+size, size);
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication has to be the most inappropriate use of recursion _ever_.  I feel your pain.

Comment: I believe you do not need the last two for loops. Probably it will work without them.

Comment: haha, thanks :P ... No need of them?? replace with 0? - After replacing with 0, it stops on 4x4 and not 5x5.. Hmm, I cant remember why I implemented them.. But it still doesnt fill up the whole space, it stops at 4x4. No Exception at 2x2 though! Slight improvement! :D

Comment: @ajb recursion and inheritance seem to be hard things for professors to come up with valid examples for. I can't tell you how many examples of inheritance I've seen that don't satisfy the "is-a" relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something along these lines would work:

```
public class indexMult {
matrix mat = new matrix();


public void calc(int Ay, int Ax, int By, int Bx, int Dy, int Dx, int size){

    System.out.println(Ay +" "+ Ax +" "+ By +" "+ Bx +" "+ Dy +" "+ Dx +" "+ size);
    if(size==2){

        mat.D[Dy][Dx] = mat.A[Ay][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];
        mat.D[Dy+1][Dx] = mat.A[Ay+1][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay+1][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];
        mat.D[Dy][Dx+1] = mat.A[Ay][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx] + mat.A[Ay][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx+1];
        mat.D[Dy+1][Dx+1] = mat.A[Ay+1][Ax] * mat.B[By][Bx+1] + mat.A[Ay+1][Ax+1] * mat.B[By+1][Bx];


    }else{

        size = size/2;  
        calc(Ay, Ax, By, Bx, Dy, Dx, size);
        calc(Ay, Ax+size, By, Bx+size, Dy, Dx+size, size);
        calc(Ay+size, Ax, By+size, Bx, Dy+size, Dx, size);
        calc(Ay+size, Ax+size, By+size, Bx+size, Dy+size, Dx+size, size);
    }
}
```

I have just replaced the loop with recursion to simply just recursion.

Comment: hm, yeah, this gives a full matrice at least :D Thanks a bunch!! :)) Do you know why mine stopped anyway?? Kinda curious about what happened, been working on it for a while before posting.

Comment: Hmm. This probably also not correct for non powers of 2. That is a lot trickier to do. I thought that was not a requirement. If you have to do that too, the dimension is 1 special case should also be covered.

Comment: Im sorry, what? The size n*n is only 2^0, 2^1, 2^2... 2^n. It would be a lot harder to go outside of this, so we are allowed to create the code to only work with the power of 2.

Comment: I think I made it! Using the formula sheet we got from our professor, and your quick fix, I think I got a working way to solve this! :D Thank you soo much, this task have costed me 2 weekends + endless of hours after school!